# White border around points in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoserver, wms, symbology

I get white borders around GeoServer point symbols in ArcMap which shouldn't be there. In QGIS the points look correct.

The styling is very basic. Here I have added a red stroke, but it doesn't matter, there is still a thin white outline in ArcMap. I get the same white outline with SVG symbols.

How can I get the points to look like they do in QGIS?

[image]

```
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Default Point</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <!-- they have names, titles and abstracts -->

            <Title>Red Square point</Title>
            <Abstract>A sample style that just prints out a red square</Abstract>
            <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
            <!-- a feature type for points -->

            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <!--FeatureTypeName>Feature</FeatureTypeName-->
                <Rule>
                    <Name>Rule 1</Name>
                    <Title>Red Square point</Title>
                    <Abstract>A red fill with 6 pixels size</Abstract>

                    <!-- like a linesymbolizer but with a fill too -->
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
                                </Fill>
                                <Stroke>
                                   <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</CssParameter>
                                   <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
                                   
                              </Stroke>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>6</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that setting the layer transparency to 1 % makes the white outlines disappear.

Right click the geoserver workspace, layer properties - Advanced and set layer transparency to 1 %:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the symbology is adding the white border? If you expand your feature in ArcMap and double-click the symbol the fill is probably red which you want but the "border section" might have the white color and probably 1 width juding by it. May be as simple as changing it to no color if you are lucky.

Comment: Thank you but there's no way to adjust the border of a wms layer

Comment: @BERA you can use SLD or SLD_BODY parameters to add to or override the style of any SLD enabled WMS (assuming you know the names of the attributes).